# Comparing two arrays and showing the difference according to each one

Tags: php, arrays, compare

So I know there's an easy way to see the difference between two arrays using array_diff.
Take a look at why I need something a bit more specific though:

Let's say we have these 2 arrays

```
$array1         $array2
   1               1
   2               -
   -               3
   4               4
   -               5
   6               -
```

The `-` indicates it is missing from the opposing array.

If `$array1` contains a missing element from `$array2`, it must be dropped from `$array1`. 
If `$array2` contains a missing element from `$array1`, it must be added to `$array1`.

If I simply perform `array_diff($array1, $array2)`, it will only return me `[2, 6]`. This isn't helpful in my scenario because I don't know which of the two arrays these items are missing from.

I did a bit of looking around and didn't seem to find out if there is a native php function that will distinguish the arrays the items are missing from.

What would be the best way to go about this? I was thinking of looping `$array1` and checking it against `$array2` and storing the results missing in a third array, and visa-versa for a fourth array.

Is that the best way? or is there an even easier, native function i can use?

Comment: what do you expect the returned array will look like based on your example above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$comparison1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$comparison2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```